# Adding a fixed width to a button using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a button with a fixed width and the text in the centre of the button, the button is defined in the main `Style.css`, but I would like to add additional styling for some pages and keep the buttons a fixed width, I have tried to use CSS - width-150px to create the width but this has no effect on the button, any thoughts

It is on a WordPress website

HTML

```
   <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/membership-profile">Membership Profile</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/password-reset">Password Reset</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
```

CSS

```
.width-150px{
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is what I can find in the style.css file

```
/* =08. Buttons
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

button,
.button,
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #199cd8;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; *display: inline;
}

/*
 * Hover
 * 1. Apply hover style also to focus state
 * 2. Remove default focus style
 * 3. Required for 'a' elements
 */

button:hover,
.button:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: #1581b2;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Active */

button:active,
.button:active,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="button"]:active {
    background-color: #199cd8;   
}

/* === Differnt Colors and Sizes Of Primary and Secondary Buttons  === */


/* Featured */

.primary-button {
    background-color: #199cd8;
}

#header-button-container .primary-button,
#header-button-container .secondary-button {
    color: #fff!important;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    }

.primary-button:hover{
    background-color: #1581b2;
}   

.secondary-button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.secondary-button:hover{
    background-color: #199cd8;
}   

.site-header .secondary-button { color: #fff; }

/*#header-button-container .secondary-button {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
    }   

.secondary-button:hover,
#header-button-container .secondary-button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #199cd8; 
    }

#header-button-container .secondary-button:hover {
    border-color: #199cd8;
}*/


/* === Default Styles === */

.button {
    margin: 5px;
    }

.button:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
    }
```

EDIT ! Using the width-150px stops the buttons from going any wider than 150px so this is more of a maximum size rather than actual size, if I reduce to to 50 all my buttons reduce in size, if I change it to 300 the buttons stay their normal size

Comment: button primary-button probably have styles on them too, inspect the item on the page with dev tools (chrome or firefox have great built in ones) and check what styles are actually being applied to the button.

Comment: [No effect?](http://jsfiddle.net/v61u1nx3/)

Comment: with only this html and css I really cannot tell you what is your problem. You must have overwritten width with another css rule. Your code works just fine when I tried it. Just in case add `!important` next to the width rule

Comment: if you use `!important` there's a good chance you'll be back here saying 'why is this width always 150px'?

Comment: From what I have tried using the width-150px stops the buttons from going any wider than 150px so this is more of a maximum size rather than actual size

Comment: Take a look of my answer, i suspect that your `<a>` tag is inside another tag with higher width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

define your **more specific classes further down in your css**.

`width-150px` is pretty specific, so it should come further down the file than less specific declarations, like `.button` and `.primary-button`.

Crucially, those preceding declarations should be at the same level of specificity, so also classes (as they are in this example).

Ideally, you would end up with:

```
.button {
    // very general button styles
}
.primary-button {
    // over-rides of button styles
    // specific primary button styles
}
.width-150px {
    // over-ride of width
}
```

**Remove unnecessary specificity from previous selectors**

You are much much better off removing unecessary specificity from previous styles than using specificity depth charges like `ID` or `!important` to over-ride. So if you find: `#wrapper-class .button` for example, take `.button` out of the wrapper class.

Some [more info](http://csswizardry.com/2014/10/the-specificity-graph/) about [specificity](http://cssguidelin.es/#specificity). [And more ...](http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/)

It's probably worth checking your **source order** in the `<head>` of the document. WordPress can get a little complicated in this area and the earlier your style file with `.width-150px` is loaded the more likely it is to be over-ridden by subsequent files.

Comment: this is a safer and better option!!

Answer (score 4):

Change HTML to:

```
<a class="primary-button" href="/membership-profile">Membership Profile</a>
```

and CSS to:

```
.primary-button{
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

This way you are applying a style (courtesy of the CSS class) to all HTML elements with the class 'primary-button'.

Comment: No, changing class is not a good solution, he might need the rest classes for extra styling.

Comment: He just added a new class width-150px, so .button.primary-button.width-150px is unique at the moment.

Comment: As I read it the OP does not want to change _all_ primary buttons. That would be simple enough.

Comment: he needs the extra classes for different styles that are more general than others `.button.primary-button.width-150px` would target just elements with all of those classes and would be more specific allowing easier over-ride (though still not really recommended) - it should be possible to do it with one extra class, correct specificity and correct source loading

Answer (score 3):

You are using css a bit wrong here. The intention is to define classes in a "semantic" way, so they have meaning. So `primary-button` is a very good class name for instance :)

There are two thing you can do: add a class, but in your case, if I understand correctly, the `primary-button` should look different depending on the context, on some pages, in a sidebar?

CSS is perfect for this: it allows you to specify a general `primary-button` but add exceptions for `primary-buttons` inside another container/selector.

Suppose your sidebar div has a class `sidebar`, you could say

```
.sidebar .primary-button {
  width: 80px;
}
```

and this will make sure that all elements with class `primary-button` inside an element with class `sidebar` have the width `80px`. For instance to make sure the buttons are smaller inside the sidebar.

It might depend on wordpress theme you use, but in general the body tag gets classes based on the page you are on. So you could use the classes from the body tag to change the appearance of all buttons on a specific page.

Comment: as a general rule, the semantic statement is correct, however, there are acceptable exceptions - I prefer to keep classes that provide very specific over-rides at the end of my css and in those I can use things that refer more specifically to general utility classes, for example `.is-hidden` or `has-width-150px` (though `has-narrow-width` would be better)

Comment: Sure there are acceptable exceptions, but shouldn't we leave those for the exceptional cases? In this case, as I understood, rendering a button in a different way based on a "context" (a div/a page) is exactly what css supports and we should use that. Not add a class `width-150` which is imho a hack.

Comment: i was under the impression the OP was trying to do something like add state with javascript as oppose to styling based on page / section position, hence the comment, but yes, those circumstances are unusual and it's best to look for another solution first

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you have to know about a tags is that they are inline elements, so in essence height or width does not affect them. But there are two ways to make it respect height or width

1. By positioning them absolutely.
2. By changing its display property to 'inline-block'

So the styles you are looking for is this

```
a{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to specify more your css code so the width will not be taken from another class:

Adding .button.primary-button.width-150px to your css will give specificity to your code and if your item has all classes button + primary-button + width-150px it will have more priority to get the 150px width.

You should also keep .width-150px; if you use this class somewhere else.

Tip: If your link/button is inside another tag like li or div or something with another width value, you might need to change the above tag's width.

From your comments i suspect that your `<a>` tag is inside a tag with higher width.

```css
.width-150px{
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}

.button.primary-button.width-150px{
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/membership-profile">Membership Profile</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/password-reset">Password Reset</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working here. You can add `!important` to override the width. E.g: `width: 150px !important;`

```css
.width-150px {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
   <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/membership-profile">Membership Profile</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/password-reset">Password Reset</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
    <a class="button primary-button width-150px" href="/test-page">Test</a>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid using `!important`, you can use more complex selector to override the style. E.g:

```
.button.primary-button.width-150px {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: use `!important` is not good advice unless it's absolutely necessary - such as in the case of inline styles added by inaccessible 3rd party javascript, even then it should only be done in a hack file included last